# RestTemplate.exchange with JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, resttemplate

I have two services (one service calls an end point `localhost:7000/create` to send a json and want expects a json )

Called service is something like this (Data is pojo class) :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create",consumes="application/json",produces = "application/json",method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Data responseForPayload(@RequestBody String data) {
    Data data= new Data();
    data.setAccountId("45");
    return data;
}
```

and the calling service restTemplate call is like this (running in :9000):

```
    String ResourceUrl = "http://localhost:7000/create";  
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    List list= new ArrayList();
    list.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity(downstreamPayload, headers);
    ResponseEntity<JSONObject> response = restTemplate.exchange(ResourceUrl, 
     HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, JSONObject.class);
```

but i am getting *response* as `{}`, when I use string instead of JSON it works fine. I used **postma**n to just to **call** the `127.0.0.1:7000/create`, it worked fine with returning the expected as json

What is my mistake here?
Thanks

Comment: Instead of JSONObject.class, you're supposed to pass a class that can be  mapped from JSON using Jackson (assuming you have Jackson in the classpath). Also, please, don't use raw types like List or ArrayList, and respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: what to do if the service is returning a totally different json that wont match the pojo . should i create one for the returning type or there is another way to solve it .

Comment: Why pass a POJO class that doesn't match the JSON in the first place? If you don't want to pass a POJO class, then pass byte[].class or String.class, and deserialize the JSON the way you want to.